# not all keywords are reserved names(?)

Tags: vba

I read [somewhere](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/syntax/keywords.htm) that **keywords** are special words that are **reserved** and used by the compiler to determine the structure of your code.

So I tried to test some keywords officially found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/keywords-visual-basic-for-applications) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/string-manipulation-keyword-summary), with surprising results:

```
Dim Me as String ' systax error
Dim Len as String ' syntax error
Dim Mid As String '  legal
Dim InStr As String ' legal
Dim Time As String ' legal
```

Can I conclude that not all keywords are reserved (in VBA)?

Furthermore, is it correct to assume that "InStr" is a keyword while "InStrRev" is not a keyword just because the second is not officially listed as keyword?

Comment: Keywords are not necessarily reserved words, and vice versa. Also the definition of "keyword" might be a bit murky. `InStr` and `InStrRev` are functions that you are shadowing, as one can do with `Time`, `MsgBox`, and so on.